# Loading compressed external javascript files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, loader

I'm looking for a solution for loading compressed external javascript files in the browser, without using http gzip compression.

I found an existing solution [here](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/read-load-files-from-zip-in-javascript/), but it wasn't updated for quite a while and I couldn't make it work properly with chrome for some of my scripts.

Comment: Just to make it clear, this will not work with a cross domain request.

Comment: "without using http gzip compression" — That's a really bad requirement.

Comment: Why would you ever want to?

Comment: @Quentin: Using Http compression, some CDNs will still charge per uncompressed kb which makes it a big problem for me.